# how to write global services in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-api

I am writing the application for i-banking , how to use angular `JS` , as we have an idea about banking , left side main link under every main link 3 to 4 sub links will be there .

How to write a common service every time whether the my login message is being available are not , how to verify , every time I will receive JSON in case my session is not available, I will send common error code.How to use across my  all module?

I have around 9 modules in my deskop application.

Comment: I think you can have Some auth service in server end that will authenticate and send responce to your angular service and on that case you can show error otherwise you will show the page needed.

Comment: hi mishra i have understand completely , what you said  that we will validate at backend using the java for validating the user session , we will send json  if the user session is not available  like { session=false, but angular js front end  all the  contollers before sould be validated by this   global services to redirect to logout page  ,  is this possible like this .}